# How to improve the following callback pattern?

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns, callback

I have the following pattern which strings together function1, 2 and 3 through their callbacks.

Assume that function1, 2 and 3 can take up to 1 second to complete. I would like to know other "better" ways of doing the same so that it doesn't turn into a monster when more callback functions are nested.

```
function1(function(cbData1){
  if(cbData1){
    function2(cbData1, function(cbData2){
      if(cbData2){
        function3(cbData2, function(cbData3){
          // success
        }
      } else {
        // failed for reason#2
      }
    });
  } else {
    //failed for reason#1
  }
});


//example function
function function2(data, callback) {
  // do dirty things
  callback(newData);
}
```

Comment: Are all calls in that same style? If so, you could create a function that calls each next function recursively.

Comment: Moreover instead of `if/else` clauses to check for fail, you could use `err` callback (node.js style) or an event.

Comment: @pimvdb they all have callback functions, but that's where the similarity ends.

Comment: Queuing is typically used to chain callbacks.

Comment: Actually, I don't think your example is really that hairy. Some smart indentation might make it look less ugly. IN my oppinion, things get really ugly when you want to write loops and when you want to write expressions at a higher level, without needing to extract each async part into a variable first and without needing to precisely specify the order of execution.

Comment: @missingno It gets a lot hairier when there are 5+ nested inside each other. Especially compared to all the other tight functions in my module.

Comment: If all functions pass the result argument along, and fail if there is no result, then you could simplify this. However, if the only similarity is that they accept callbacks, you could look into a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: @pimvdb Thanks for your suggestion. However the solution needs to be vanilla JS.

Comment: @Timmy: You can always use some library-based approaches like people suggested but IMO, the only way to *really* get to of the nesting, without messing up with variable scope and things like that, is to use some sort of compiler that lets you write async code in a dialect of JS that doesn't need nesting. Unfortunately I don't know what compiler to recommend you since I haven't coded in JS for a while. http://altjs.org/

Comment: @missingno the only "compiler"/builder I have available for this are minifiers and concatenators. If you're interested, take a look at Jeremy J Starcher's solution that I selected as the answer.

Comment: @Timmy: that solution only works if your calling patter is sequential though. Another problem is that f1,f2 and f3 don't naturally share variables (you need to hoist variables to the top manually). If you want to go that way I would rather use something less hacky such as the async library pimvdb suggested.

Comment: @missingno my problem is indeed about sequential calls. Additionally, I can use something like http://jsfiddle.net/Ce7cb/ to solve the issue about callback data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I played with really nasty callbacks, I ended up doing something like this:

```
// Typed on the fly, be kind
var callbackList = [];  // A list of functions to call in order.

function doNextCallback() {
  if (callbackList.length) {
    var f = callbackList.shift(); // Get the next callback function
    window.setTimeout(f);         // Give breathing space.
  }
}

// Set up our callbacks
callbackList.push(f1);
callbackList.push(f2);
callbackList.push(f3);

// Start it happening.
doNextCallback();          


function f1() {
  console.log("Busy busy");
  doNextCallback();
}

function f2() {
  console.log("Busy busy");
  doNextCallback();
}
function f3() {
  console.log("Busy busy");
  doNextCallback();
}
```

I had it all wrapped up in a nice object, but you get the idea.

This also made it very easy to re-arrange callbacks or to call just two of them in a big loop for testing purposes.

Comment: I like it. Your solution is also easy to unit test :) Thank you, Sir!

Comment: @Timmy -- the version that I have wraps everything up in an object, so that your inner functions can start their own callback list.  When the inner functions end, they can call the parent callback.  But yes, ease of testing is *exactly* why I came up with that ... pattern?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to organize the callbacks in a chain. Look at [Chain of Responsibility](http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html) pattern.

So you will create an object containing the function to execute and callback function to execute if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but UML diagrams and long texts put me off :)

Comment: You have to be strong in order to be a good developer ;). Try to understand this text :)

Comment: @Timmy Mikhail is quite right. If you want to swim, you'll get wet. Why ask for improvement, if you're not prepared to do what it takes to effectively improve it? I know UML can be quite intimidating, but actually it's not that hard and it will make you a better programmer.